# Can't find replacement ECU/ECM

Tags: hyundai, electronic-control-module, i30

I recently had some water damage to my 2016 Hyundai I-30 ECM and now I need a replacement, however I'm unable to find the exact Part using the part number. My part no. is 39127-2b693 but no luck anywhere. Can another ECM work with a different part number?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the part number you've given directly off of the ECU?

Comment: Did you try local salvage yards?